# SQL Server 2008 > how to get service startup parameter values by query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, configuration

Is it possible to query for the SQL Server 2008 service startup parameter values using T-SQL?  I'm specifically looking for the -g parameter that indicates how much [memory that SQL Server will leave available for memory allocations within the SQL Server process, but outside the SQL Server memory pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx) [msdn reference].

Comment: Do any of the values in sys.configurations look promising?

Comment: @Martin Smith: I don't think any of those settings is really what Sean is looking for (and that's why I deleted my post, too). I don't see any setting that corresponds to this -g switch - and unfortunately, neither TechNet nor MSDN seem to be shedding a lot of light on this either....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CLR procedure and query the [SCM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) for the current setting. Or look it up in the registry with [xp_regread](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Undoc/UndocExtSP.htm). Both will get you the *configured* value, which may not be the runtime value.

But there is a caveat, namely that -g is such an obsolete flag that nobody should be using it and you shouldn't be looking for it. Is only relevant for x86 32bit platforms and 32 bit is dead.

Comment: So, if -g is obsolete, then how does one configure the quantity of available memory for memory allocations within the SQL Server process, but outside the SQL Server memory pool, in a 64bit environment?

Comment: In a 64 bit environment there is not need for -g. The VA space is huge.

Answer (score 1):

I just started mine like that

```
P:\>net start MSSQLSERVer /g 5000
```

And then I ran this

```
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Command Line Startup Parameters','/g'
```

Here is the output

2010-05-07 14:11:09.510 Server  Command Line Startup Parameters:    /g

As you can see you can do a search for /g to see if it was started with the /g switch

More info about how to use sp_readerrorlog here: [Read the error log with T-SQL](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Read_the_error_log_with_T-SQL)